The render does not work if I turn on the visibility of fur
I have such a problem; I created a beautiful cat.  But the render does not work when I turn on the visibility of the fur. As soon as I turn off the fur, the render loads the image in a couple of seconds. I do not know how to fix it. I am a beginner. 1 photo - screenshot with fur, 2 photo - render without fur. I can't show you what the rendering process with fur looks like, the computer freezes. How do I set up the particle rendering correctly? What am I doing wrong?


The hair rendering is heavy. Check if you don't have some ridiculous settings set for render.
Particle Properties -> Children -> Render Amount
Check the settings that simplify the viewport rendering and hide the problem.
Particle Properties -> Viewport Display -> Amount
Render Properties -> Simplify -> Viewport -> Child Particles

I had a similar issue back a few months ago, my problem was a way to high amount of B-Spline steps (Particle Properties>Render>Path).
Make sure you didn't use a way too high number, mostly 5 is more than enough.
Hope it helps
